# How do I query another collection within mongo aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a DB similar to 
Collection 1

```
{group_name: "group_1", key_name: "key_name_1"},
{group_name: "group_1", key_name: "key_name_2"},
{group_name: "group_2", key_name: "key_name_3"},
{group_name: "group_2", key_name: "key_name_4"},
{group_name: "group_2", key_name: "key_name_5"}
```

Collection 2

```
{subtype: "A", key_name: "key_name_1"},
{subtype: "B", key_name: "key_name_1"},
{subtype: "A", key_name: "key_name_2"},
{subtype: "B", key_name: "key_name_2"},
{subtype: "C", key_name: "key_name_2"},
{subtype: "A", key_name: "key_name_3"},
{subtype: "A", key_name: "key_name_4"}
```

I want a count of objects from `collection2` per each group.
I am trying to use aggregate as below:

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
{
    $group : {
        _id: "$group_name",
        total : { $sum : db.collection2.find({key_name : "$key_name"}).count()}
   }
}
])
```

Expected Output:

```
{_id:"group_1",total:5},
{_id:"group_2",total:2}
```

Actual Output:

```
{_id:"group_1",total:0},
{_id:"group_2",total:0}
```

> Note:
>
> ```
> db.collection1.aggregate([ {
>     $group : {
>         _id: "$group_name",
>         total : { $sum : db.collection2.find({key_name : "key_name_1"}).count()}
>         } 
>     } 
> ])
> ```
>
> Above Code produces the
>   following output which is expected.
>
> ```
> {_id:"group_1",total:4}, 
> {_id:"group_2",total:6}
> ```

I need a solution in `pymongo` or `mongoshell`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation is for

```
db.collection1.aggregate([ {   
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "collection2",
         localField: "key_name",
         foreignField: "key_name",
         as: "collection2_docs"
       }
  },{
    $group : {
        _id: "$group_name",
        total : { $sum : { $size: "$collection2_docs" } }
        } 
    } 
])
```

Comment: this works. minor correction: `total : { $sum : { $size: "$collection2_docs" } }`

Comment: @ixx1 Thx, fixed it.